# How to draw a vertical line at intersection point

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following code I use axhline command to draw a horizontal line along x-axis. Now I want to draw a vertial line at the point where two lines have already crossed each other. I can not use axvline because I don't know the value of intersection. In case of axhline I draw that line at 50 percent probability value.

```
x=[1, 1.5, 2, 5, 5.5, 6 ]
y=[1, 1, 0.89189189, 0.01086957, 0.01190476, 0]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y,marker='o')
plt.axhline(0.5, color='r')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it by finding the equation of the straight line connecting the 3rd and the 4th point. This is not a general solution but tailor made for your particular problem and data set.

```
x=[1, 1.5, 2, 5, 5.5, 6 ]
y=[1, 1, 0.89189189, 0.01086957, 0.01190476, 0]

# Compute the equation of the line connecting 3rd and 4th point
m = (y[3]-y[2])/(x[3]-x[2]) # Slope
c = y[3]-m*x[3] # y-Intercept
x_inter = (0.5-c)/m # Desired intersection point

# Your plotting commands here
plt.axvline(x_inter, color='g')
```

**Output**

[image]